# Inject a Javsacript SDK to several selected pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web application and I want to inject a JavaScript SDK to several selected pages during the page load of one specific page(for example HomePage.aspx).

I was thinking of a method like this to call on Page_Load of HomePage.aspx

```
  injectScript(list of selected pages, script){
    for each page in selected pages{
      page.embed(script)
    }
  }
```

But can we use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` to register scripts for other pages while calling it from HomePage.aspx?

Is there any better way?

**Update 1:**

In nutshell, All these pages share a master page but adding this JavaScript SDK to master page will make the SDK available to all child pages. I want to have a way to toggle(on/off) this SDK in each page based on user input(saved in a database).

There are more than 30 aspx pages and adding a method to page_load in each page is not feasible.

Is there any simple way to do achieve this functionality?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? this doesn't seem to make sense, editing ASP.NET pages from another page seems shady for the least...

Comment: Do all these pages share a similar control (i.e. Header or Master Page)? If so, dynamically adding the script to the ````Page.Header```` is going to be a better option.

Comment: @LaurentS. Yes it is shady for me too, It is why I am thinking of better ways. What I am actually doing is, I have a javascript SDK and the admin user should have the option to include or not to include this SDK for each aspx page using the admin dashboard.

Comment: @JohnPete22 All these pages share a master page but adding this JavaScript SDK to master page will make the SDK available to all child pages. I want to have a way to toggle(on/off) this SDK in each page based on user input

Comment: You're going into a very wrong direction. If you want to do this you should save somewhere (database, file, ...) the wished state for this SDK on each and every page, then when using the page check for this data. Adding physically things into the files will hardly work.

Comment: @LaurentS. There are more than 30 pages, and adding a method to page_load of each page is a tedious task. Is there a one-shot approach?

Comment: Just add everything to the master page which is from what I understood shared by all pages. Or to each master page if you happen to have several. Then with the code challenge the datasource with page name to find whether the SDK should be included on this page or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if anyone wondering the same, here is the solution I came up; use the following method inside Page_Load of the master page.( You will have to populate the list with appropriate data-source)

```
    private void EnableSDK()
    {
        List<string> pages = new List<string>(); //selected aspx page names(not class names) 
        foreach (string page in pages)
        {
            if (page == System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath))
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "somekey", "somescript", true);
            }
        }
    }
```